# I have a simple calc field that works for all numbers except one certain one

Tags: rounding

Can anyone help with this issue? I have a very simple sample sample access 2010 db with 3 records that should be producing the same amount in a calculated field on a report, but are not. I cant figure out why my rounding formula for the CALCULATED TOTAL on the Purchase Form is rounding perfectly for ALL combinations of numbers EXCEPT the numbers in a certain record. The problem is totally reproduce-able. I have also created a report so you can easily see the issue. The three records have the same TOTAL PRICE, but one of them is rounding up to $8 when it should be staying at $7. Something in the data is not as it seems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You should include the query and the trouble record in your actual question.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, see [mcve]. I'm pretty sure you can reduce that 800k sample file to something much smaller ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm just glad he didn't say 800MB ^ ^

Comment: I dont see how to upload a file.  is there a way to attach a file to my question.  Ive got it zipped to quite small.  thanks jm